# How do I make a boolean field required in a z3c.form?

Tags: forms, plone, z3c.form

I'm using z3c.form to create a form in Plone 4.1.4. I need a boolean field which is required: the user must tick the box. (In my case, the user must agree to the terms and conditions.)

Using `required=True` for the field doesn't work: I can submit the form without checking the checkbox.

This is what my code looks like:

```
from five import grok
from plone.directives import form
from zope import schema
from z3c.form import button


from Products.CMFCore.interfaces import ISiteRoot
from Products.statusmessages.interfaces import IStatusMessage


class ITestSchema(form.Schema):
    hasApprovedConditions = schema.Bool(
        title=u'I agree to the Terms and Conditions.',
        required=True,
    )


class TestForm(form.SchemaForm):
    grok.name('test-form')
    grok.require('zope2.View')
    grok.context(ISiteRoot)

    schema = ITestSchema
    ignoreContext = True

    @button.buttonAndHandler(u'Send')
    def handleApply(self, action):
        data, errors = self.extractData()
        if errors:
            self.status = self.formErrorsMessage
            return

        IStatusMessage(self.request).addStatusMessage(u'Thanks', 'info')
        self.request.response.redirect(self.context.absolute_url())
```

The form shows the checkbox and label, but there is no indication that the field is required and indeed it isn't: I can submit the form without ticking the checkbox.

I'm extending these known good sets:

- http://dist.plone.org/release/4.1.4/versions.cfg
- http://good-py.appspot.com/release/dexterity/1.2?plone=4.1.4

They pin z3c.form to version 2.5.1 but I also tried version 2.6.1.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have to use constraint here, like Giacomo suggests to have only one valid answer (False is not acceptable).  In the more generic case (I realize this is not it) of simply needing a validation where True/False are both accepted, but a value cannot be omitted, I believe that schema.Bool(required=True, default=None) paired with a radio widget will be the best solution (there is a distinct possible problem of a checkbox widget conflating False with omitted value, which means that a checkbox widget is a UI fail except for the case you describe, which it is suited to with the constraint added).

Comment: The nature of booleans is to be either `false` or `true`, `none` is not in the scope. Required defines, that a value must be given, which is also the case, if the user doesn't tick the checkbox: it's `false`. Just my 2 Øre.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use a constraint like this:

```python
def validateAccept(value):
    if not value == True:
        return False
    return True

class ITestSchema(form.Schema):
    hasApprovedConditions = schema.Bool(
        title=u'I agree to the Terms and Conditions.',
        required=True,
        constraint=validateAccept,
    )
```

*More info*:

- http://plone.org/products/collective.examples.userdata

Comment: I thought I tried that. Must have made a mistake. Thanks. (The only 'flaw' is that in the form the field isn't explicitly labelled as required.)

Answer (score 0):

to respond to the "flaw" you note @Mark van Lent - just add a:

```
description=_(u'Required'),
```